# Create HTTP POST method in ASP.NET which accepts CGI variables

Tags: asp.net, http-post

I have an ASP.NET (.NET v4) web application running on IIS 7.5.  I have a 3rd party which wants to pass information to my system.  They support passing this information using HTTP POST, the information they provide is:

> "This method simply calls a script on your server and passes each
>   field as a CGI variable.  When you have received the data your server
>   should return a '1' on a line by itself to indicate success.  Anything
>   else will generate an error on our server which will be investigated.
>
> To set up this delivery method we need a URL to post to.  We can use
>   HTTP or HTTPS."

My web application currently implements many WCF services but as I don't know what the variables passed in will be I cannot define a specific contract.  Can I create a normal aspx page which they can post to and then read each of the parameters passed and do the appropriate processing.

If I do this how do I send back a line containing '1'?

Do I need to do anything else to make this HTTP POST compatible.

Comment: Grab the data by simply getting the http POST vars; and as for returning the 1 I would imagine that returning it is just as simple as Response.Write("1");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last time I had to tackle a similar situation, i did it using a standard ASPX page, and it all worked quite well.

In my case the output was XML, so I had to make sure that I changed the output mime type to match "text/xml" in my case.. "text/plain" I would guess in yours..

Anyway, C# sharp code below, and make sure that your ASPX file has ONLY the very top line in, that is:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="register.aspx.cs" Inherits="myservices.register" ContentType="text/xml" %>
```

and nothing else, no carriage returns or anything.

Then do all your work in the code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      Response.Clear();
      Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

      //Get your CGI variables here...  you will have to get them to tell you what to expect
      string myparam = (string)Request.QueryString["myparam"];

      //do what ever you need here with your variables      

      Response.Write("1");
      Response.End();

    }// End page load handler
```

If you need to follow the one with a carriage return, then i believe you can use the carriage return property in the system.environment object, but I've not got doc's to hand to look it up.  That should however get you started.

The MOST important thing to remember is to make sure NOTHING is output from the aspx, not even a carriage return.

I've previously written an article on my Blog about how to use this method for producing phone directories for Cisco-IP phones if you want to read it.  You can find it here: http://shawtyds.wordpress.com/2009/09/26/cisco-ip-phone-directories-using-c/